# Good partition strategy if I want to change distros frequently?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem

I want to dual-boot Windows 8(already installed) and Ubuntu 12.10. The thing is I would like to try out different distros over the coming months.

So my question is what would be a good partition strategy to make it easy to migrate from one distro to another.

I know the first step would be to create a separate /home partition (in addition to the root and swap partition). What about other stuff? I might also have apache installed so  would i need to either migrate /etc/www manually between distros or create a partition for /etc?

Comment: You mean that, in addition to /home, you want to have /root and /etc common for these distros you intend to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest single help in my own distribution experimentation isn't partitioning: It's virtualization. I've got VirtualBox set up with over a dozen virtual machines. It's very easy to install a new distribution, delete an unused one, back up a whole virtual disk, and so on, without messing with partition tables or risking my main installation.

If you must have direct hardware access, my recommendation is to look into an LVM configuration. This enables you to add, delete, and resize logical volumes to hold filesystems much as you'd add, delete, or resize ordinary files. This greatly simplifies management of multiple Linux distributions, since you don't need to be as concerned about the placement and size of particular partitions. OTOH, some distributions (including Ubuntu's desktop editions) have poor LVM support, so you may need to jump through some extra hoops to get them installed on LVMs.

Beyond that, you cannot put `/etc` on its own partition (or logical volume), since that must be part of the installation's root filesystem. (Think about it: `/etc/fstab`, which tells the computer where filesystems are found, is in `/etc`.) In theory, I suppose you might be able to make `/etc/www` a separate partition, but I wouldn't recommend it; if Apache has different requirements from one distribution to another, you might not be able to share those configuration files. Copying them over and tweaking them manually might work, though.

Sharing swap space is perfectly do-able. So is sharing the `/home` partition, with the caveat that user programs can have varying requirements between distributions, so you shouldn't try to share your user home directory (`/home/ned` or whatever you use). You can avoid such sharing by using different usernames on the different distributions, or you can use account management tools like `usermod` to link an account to a directory name that's not identical to the account name, so that the user `ned` could be linked to `/home/nedu` for Ubuntu, `/home/nedf` for Fedora, or whatever.

Comment: I finally decided on 3 separate partitions for /, swap and /home. LVM support is poor in Ubuntu, since it does not allow me to manually choose my partitions. For now I am going without LVM. Also these links helped me a lot(similar advice to what you provided) :-  (http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/03/ubuntu-12-10-installation-and-disk-partitioning-guide/) (http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/the-pain-free-guide-to-switching-linux-distros-478667)